# Handling/Passing multiple parameters from feature file in gherkin

Tags: c#, automation, bdd, acceptance-testing, gherkin

How to I pass multiple parameters using feature.

I am aware of usage of "Examples:" concept but it's making feature file more complicated and unreadable in some manner

Example:

```
Scenario Outline: To verify that default value for some timeout when invalid/remove is set for some timeout parameter

When <parameterA> is <action> with <parameterB> for <someOtherParameterPair> in <fileName>
Then <parameterA> is updated with value <parameterB> for <someOtherParameterPair> in <fileName> as per defined <action>
Examples:
|parameterA  |parameterB  |action|someOtherParameterPair|fileNameWithSectionName|
|oneParameter|twoParameter|update|key:Value             |abc.config:appSettings |
|oneParameter|twoParameter|delete|key:Value             |def.config:appSettings |
```

Here, I have around 7  parameters which are coming from testcase(which I have tried to accomodated in 5 parameters due to limitation)

I would be splitting "someOtherParameterPair" and "fileNameWithSectionName" into two using split in step definition file. So in total I have around 7 parameters which will be used in Test Case.

But I am not sure whether accepting such huge number of parameters from Given/When/Then statements are feasible. It's also making my test case unreadable.

In above scenario, I am trying to modify some parameters(which I am passing from feature file so that my When/Then statements could modify) present in *.config file present at certain location.

After which I need to execute the testcase.

In the same manner, I have other(most of them) cases as well in my test suite.

Please help me is BDD right  approach. Is BDD going to create some issues in maintenance as I am seeing lots of things (almost everything from) feature file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't write your features like this. Instead of using your feature to describe `how` you are testing something, use it to explain `what` you are testing and `why` you are testing it

Generally this means you don't need to use examples, and you certainly never need to use complicated examples like you've got. You can always push the usage of examples down to a lower level e.g. the step definitions.

In this case it looks like you should be writing a unit test. There is nothing of business value described in this scenario.

BDD is about describing behaviour and using that to drive development. You can't use it to test things after they have been written!!

Comment: @@diabolist ..but my scenarios are like I need to modify some parameters  in *.config file followed by execution on UI
Then Again some other parameters in *.config followed by execution and so on... 

In similiar manner I have various test scenarios where I need to modify different config file 3 to 4 times and then check the behaviour on UI 
It's kind of an Unit test replica but how can I include it into BDD

Comment: If I don't use examples and try to update the *.config for each scenario individually then I need to write separate configModiication function for each and individual test case(3-4 permutation and combination for scenario) and that would lead to stack of same functions which does same thing but with different parameters....... Also, naming such functions with same functionality will also would be a task.

Comment: You should be using a unit test tool to do work like that. BDD is not really about testing its much more about collaboration and driving development. What you seem to be doing is using a really slow tool, for doing lots of intensive low level tests. You'll find that the execution time for these sorts of tests is huge, and that tools don't support the kind of work you are doing. This is not becuase the tools are no good, its because you are using the wrong tools for this particular job.

Comment: ya i know. Can't help it..requirement is in such a way that can't change the tool :).. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example tables should not exceed 3 columns. Otherwise, it is quite impossible to understand the relationship between columns, the test approach, the test objective, and to analyze the test results.

You need to clarify the test objective to be able to refactor this.
possible steps for optimization:

1. If you test that some parameter is changed from the value `oneParameter` to `twoParameter` in some conditions, what is the reason for having `<parameterA>` column? If the parameter should be overwritten, its previous value is not essential, and you can just ignore it.
2. What is the relation between `someOtherParameterPair` and `fileNameWithSectionName`? Do you really need these columns to be separated in your table? Possibly you can combine them into `<pathToTheParameterPair>`.

with the assumption above, you scenario can be simplified as follows:

```
Scenario Outline: To verify that default value for some timeout when invalid/remove is set for some timeout parameter

When SettingName is <action> with <parameterB> for <pathToTheParameterPair> 
Then SettingName is updated with value <parameterB> for <pathToTheParameterPair> as per defined <action>
Examples:
| parameterB   |action | pathToTheParameterPair |
| twoParameter |update | abc.config:appSettings:key:Value |
| twoParameter |delete | def.config:appSettings:key:Value |
```